# how to send email in joomla if my webpage is run on localhost?

Tags: joomla1.5

i used login module in my webpage. in that by clicking on 'forgot password?' i need to give an email-address but by clicking on Send button the error is 'could not install mail function'.
so, please give suggestion, my web page is running on localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your computer's version of php does not have working mail. I would suggest you A: reinstall joomla, B: find the hash function in the php and replace the old password hash with a new one, or C: find a mail plugin for your version of xamp/wamp/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Windows platform [try the following](http://www.programmingfacts.com/send-email-localhostxampp-wamp/):

1. Open the php.ini file. For XAMPP, it is located in
   C:\XAMPP\php\php.ini
2. Change the localhost to the smtp server name of
   your ISP. Leave smtp_port as 25.
3. Change sendmail_from from me@localhost.com to your domain email address which will be used as the from address
4. Restart XAMPP or WAMP (apache server)
5. Try to send the mail using the mail() function

I think it should solve your problem.